# Printing Out One Array in Multiple Colums (Is It Possible?)

Tags: c, printf

After printing out elements of an array in a column **(arr[i]\n)**, is there a way to print other arrays in columns next to it, not below?

Practically I'm working with one array to make things easier. That means printing values of the array, then changing those values and printing the array again, multiple times...

Now I've heard what I might use is a **carriage return (\r)**, but that doesn't seem to work, wherever I put it.

Does anyone know about some different option (I'm not reconstructing the program, just want to adjust the print if possible - therefore no sample)
or can show proper usage of (\r), if this is supposed to work in my case and I'm missing something?

**Edited Question**

> Is it possible to go on the first line after printing out text on
>   multiple lines (\n), and adding another text next (\t) to it?

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Show some examples of the input, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: Take the elements from the arrays *in parallel* and print them in row.

Comment: As I said in my original question I'm not reconstructing the program, just want to know if it's possible to go on the first line after printing out text, and adding another text next to it - therefore no sample, or example.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I really need to organize it the way I mentioned...

Comment: You could use a `gotoxy` function though there is not one in *standard* C library. But no example, no sample: no help. Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). One suggestion: print the first value without a `newline` and then print the second value, third value etc and finally print a `newline`. Note: your idea of revisiting each line won't work once the number of lines exceeds the console buffer size.

Comment: Hmmmm `\n` is often call "line-feed".  If output wants to print on the same line, best to avoid sending that control character.  `'\r'` (return) _might_ work.  Still better to avoid this approach.  C does not well support a do-over.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think that would be printing the array in a row, as said by Eugene Sh., I really don't need that, for organizing reasons...

Comment: @chux As I mentioned, \r does not seem to work for this. That is in case I'm doing everything right.

Comment: @SamS said "I'm not reconstructing the program". Don't be too fixed. If the program needs restructuring, then archive what you have and do so. The way to approach this is, for example, `printf("%8d %8d %8d\n", arr[i], brr[i], crr[i]);`

Comment: Curios, why _first_ line?  If anything, I'd expect you would want code to remember a line position and then revert back to it.  So even if "goto first line" existed, to go back 1 line, after printing millions of lines, going back to the first and then forward 999,999 lines, seems impractical.

Comment: You might want to look at the ncurses library.

Comment: @SamS you did not take in any of the comments. Commenters have suggested various things but without a ***concrete example*** it is just guess work. Please notice the reason for several "close" votes. Your question was simply "is there a way to print other arrays in columns next to it" and my previous comment shows how to do that. My ( and other) earlier comment says that is is impractical to revisit previously printed lines.

Comment: @FredK Rather stupid problem to install library for, but I'll look into it.

Comment: Escpecially if the console output is redirected to a disk file - won't work.

Comment: The C language itself does not have any built-in way to place text on the screen other than line-by-line, so to go back up to print on a previously printed line must use some external library that is specific to the platform you are running on.

Comment: @SamS C has very, very little built in by design.

Comment: @WeatherVane I appreciate your effort, but "Edited Question" is yes or no question, yet nobody answered... I may later add some examples, but with most problems it just seems easier and less time consuming to find out how to resolve the problem on your own.

Comment: @SamS: if you are asking about C the answer is NO.

Comment: @FredK Alright, thank you.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'm happy with that.

Comment: @SamS The reason people are asking for an example is because they're attempting to figure out what you really need and give you the best solution.  What you're asking sounds very much like an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).